# How to disable flash plugin in Chrome and IE using Selenium/Java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

Used the following code for Chrome...But the flash is not disabled for Chrome..
Even I require the code for IE as well

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
Map<String, Object> prefs = new HashMap<String, Object>();
prefs.put("profile.default_content_settings.state.flash",0);
//profile.default_content_settings.popups
options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", prefs);  
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",System.getProperty("user.dir")+"\\chromedriver.exe");
driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

Comment: Are you trying to disable Adobe's flash plugin or Chrome's bundled flash?

Comment: Adobe Flash Player..Also I require the code for the IE..That would be helpful

Comment: You could either [disable external plugins](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27210708/disabling-flash-in-chrome), thus disabling Adobe Flash Player, or you could [disable specifically Adobe's plugin](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17113477/disable-flash-in-saucelabs-selenium-webdriver). I don't know about IE, though.

Comment: Thanks...Could U provide the code for Chrome...

Answer (score 4):

This is how i got it to work for Chrome:

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("--disable-bundled-ppapi-flash");
WebDriver webDriver = new org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver(options);
```

Comment: This will disable Chrome's bundled flash, not Adobe's flash plugin.

Comment: I don't really get the difference. Isn't the embedded plugin provided by Adobe?
(see: https://www.adobe.com/software/flash/about/)

However, when I use the argument, no Flash Plugin appears in the about:plugins section anymore and Flash doesn't work for me anymore.

Comment: The embedded plugin is provided by Adobe, but you can still have their regular plugin installed on top of that. Check the second question on this link: https://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player/kb/flash-player-google-chrome.html

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have two options when working with Chrome. I don't know about IE, though. Your only option might be to manually configure it.

#### Disabling external plugins

Based on [Disabling flash in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27210708/disabling-flash-in-chrome). This will disable any external plugin, including Adobe Flash Player.

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.AddArguments("--disable-plugins-discovery");
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

#### Disabling Adobe Flash Player plugin

Based on [Disable flash in saucelabs/selenium webdriver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17113477/disable-flash-in-saucelabs-selenium-webdriver). This should disable only Adobe's plugin.

```
Map<String, Object> prefs = new HashMap<>();
prefs.put("plugins.plugins_disabled", "Adobe Flash Player");
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", prefs);  
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure the above is for java. If you are using C#, things like setExperimentalOption are re-named to AddAdditionalCapability etc.

Comment: It's Java. The question has the Java tag after all.